# Python - Storing index number of an array with comparison of the value with an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out how to store the index of a value or both. Steps:

- Scan array (one by one)
- compare each value is greater than a certain number
- If it is greater, save the index number and value
- Next, check next number, is it greater than certain number? move to next
- if the number is less than certain number, break

---

```
y1 = []                 % Is a 128 length array
flagcheck = 0           %check for when found a number greater than needed
startofindex = []       %Place to save where the 1st number was found
endofindex = []         %Place where end

for g in y1:
    if (y1.count(g) > 0.001):
        startofindex.append(enumerate(y1.count(g))) % I know this won't work but I can't seem to find the best sol'n
        flagcheck = 1;
        while (flagcheck == 1):
            for g in y1:
                if (y1.count(g) <= 0.001):
                    endofindex.append(enumerate(y1.count(g)))
                    break
```

I want to use index to format a graph's axis for particular points.

Comment: Why are you inventing your own comment character??? Use *actual python commments* Anyway, it isn't obvious to me exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps consider giving a couple of examples of the behavior you want

Comment: At the time of writing this I was writing matlab code and well unconsciously added % instead of # commenting. Sorry.
So, I have this list of values, 128 of them. I want to graph these Values against an X-axis. It can't be the values vs 128 because, each one represents a certain frequency for a Fourier Fast Transform (FFT). So, once I can figure out the Value with specific placement of it in the array, I can convert that number on a graph. I.E... value 1.0 at a[3]. Then graphing xaxis a[3] would be converted to a frequency number. I wish I could draw it out and post it.